# conditional className in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

May be a subtle problem, but i don't like the way it appears when i inspect elements in the browser

Sometimes i need to add a class to an element in react using ternary operator and that may leave some space when the condition returns **false**

for exampe:

```
<div className={`container ${some condition ? 'bg-green' : ''}`}
```

when condition is `true`, the class is added to the `div` but when it is `false`, there is an ugly space shown in the element when inspect

```
<div class="container  ">
```

Is it acceptable?? or a bad practice??, is there a good solution for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That shouldn't be a big issue, but you can remove the space before the ternary operator (and add it in the `.bg-green` branch)

```
<div className={`container${some condition ? ' bg-green' : ''}`}
```

I haven't tried, but you might add a `.trim()` as well like below, but I don't think you need it.

```
<div className={`container${some condition ? ' bg-green' : ''}`.trim()}
```

Demo:

```js
console.log(`"container${true ? ' bg-green' : ''}"`)
console.log(`"container${false ? ' .bg-green' : ''}"`)
```

Comment: ```{`container${some condition ? ' bg-green' : ''}`}```

in that way container class won't work at all!!

Comment: What about plan B? ```<div className={`container ${some condition ? 'bg-green' : ''}`}.trim()```

Comment: yes, that way worked, but i had to move trim() inside the curly brackets
```<div className={`container ${some condition ? 'bg-green' : ''}`trim()}.```

Thank you

Comment: now i see the two methods works perfectly, i didn't notice the space you made before the ```bg-green``` class, thank you

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't really bother you too much, 
it's not a big deal...

Anyway, 
add the spacing as part of the condition to solve it:

```
<div className={`container${someCondition ? ' bg-green' : ''}`}
```

or

```
const classes = ['container'].concat(condition ? 'foo' : [];

return <div className={classes.join(' ')} />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable?? or a bad practice??, is there a good solution for it?

It's totally acceptable, and not a bad practice: it doesn't make any practical difference to the HTML if there's some extra space in a class attribute.

One neat solution, which also simplifies, eg. using multiple conditional classes, is to use the [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package. This is a small JavaScript utility function for this exact purpose (ie. conditionally setting classes). Using `classnames` your example would look something like:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
...
<div className={classNames('container', { 'bg-green': someCondition })}>
```

...this way the `container` class will always be present, and the `bg-green` class will be present only when `someCondition` is `true`. This makes it easy to add more conditional classes if you need to (you can add more keys to that object), and you don't need to worry about whitespace.